# Es posible crear un dns record www.example.com/nombre_ciudad?

Tags: aws, dns

hola estoy tratando de crear un cname para redirigir a un sitio web en aws, pero necesito que el nombre de dominio quede por ejemplo: [www.nombreddedominio.com/ciudad](http://www.nombreddedominio.com/ciudad) y redirija la url de la app amplify en aws.

Alguien me puede guiar con esto porfa.

Comment: ¿Revisaste [esto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-google-domains.html)?

Answer (score 1):

No se si entendí bien.
Podrías crear un .htaccess y la carpeta de la ruta a donde va tu dominio, en el htaccess rediriges a donde te plazca

Como sugerencia, tengo entendido un subdominio ideal sería ciudad.nombreddedominio.com así puedes crear el cname y dirigirlo a otra IP donde pudieras tener tu aplicación.

Comment: crisnoel te comento que eso del cname es lo ideal, y el problema es que no estoy usuando un servidor web como nginx por ejemplo donde yo si puedo controlar estoy, lo que tengo en un dominio en google domain y una web app en amplify de aws.

Comment: Temo que no se va a poder entonces bro, bueno, al menos yo no e visto un cname que contenga dominio.com/subdominio, si solo es el dominio y no tienes servidor web creo que no se va a poder. Si me equivoco, espero vengan a corregirme y también espero y lo puedas resolver (:

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo contigo, fue una petición del cliente pero ya investigando mas eso no es posible, la solucion que tengo es crear los cname y manejar el / con las rutas de react